# regex_match for length only

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I have this regex_match here

```
regex_match[/^{0,100}+$/]
```

I am trying to just to validate the length of my string, but I get this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 7

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 911
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to use: `/^.{0,100}$/`; although I would prefer `strlen($str) <= 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
regex_match[/^.{0,100}$/]
```

Comment: `.` does not match newlines unless you explicitly tell it to with the appropriate modifier.

Comment: You should probably add `/m` modifier to match newline chars as well.

Answer (score 3):

although I'm admittedly unclear on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, why not just use strlen?

strlen($string) >= 100 should give the same results.

Comment: Agreed regex is overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

The {0,100} bit requires something to repeat, e.g. `[a-z]{0,100}` but your examples has nothing. You might want ot use a `.` for "any character"

Comment: Not quite - `.` does not match newlines unless you tell it to with the appropriate modifier.